# Масштаб графика в R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Здраствуйте.
Есть данные, которые разбиты на кластеры. В данных после кластеризации появились 
выбросы, которые увеличивают длину осей Ox, Оу. Тем самым, при визуализации получается такой график, где большинство основных данных не видно из-за масштаба.
Как можно ограничить оси в зависимости от входных данных? Через xlim и ylim не получилось, либо я что-то не так делал.

[image: График]

**[Пример данных](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ecu1urunkg8qa2k/pca_1991.csv?dl=0)**

```
library('ggplot2')
library('proto')

data_89 <- read.csv(file = 'C:/Users/Kirill/Notebook Projects/Risks/clusters/pca_clusters/pca_1991.csv', sep =';', header = TRUE)
data_89

# stat_ellipse is not part of the base ggplot package
source("https://raw.github.com/low-decarie/FAAV/master/r/stat-ellipse.R") 

ggplot(data_89) +
  geom_point(aes(x=pc_1, y=pc_2, color=factor(cluster)), size=3, shape=20) +
  stat_ellipse(aes(x=pc_1,y=pc_2,fill=factor(cluster)),
               geom="polygon", level=0.95, alpha=0.2) +
  guides(color=guide_legend("Cluster"),fill=guide_legend("Cluster"))
```

Comment: Ваш пример не воспроизводим. Данные должны быть выложены куда-то. При небольшим объёме данных, самое простое - использовать функцию `dput() ` и знать данные текстом. Но вообще, в таком вопросе имеет смысл сгенерировать простенький датасет.

Comment: Приложил данные по ссылке "Пример данных"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот момент отлично показан в [RStudio Data Visualization Cheat Sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/ggplot2-cheatsheet-2.1.pdf). Вообще, очень рекомендую их шпаргалки.

---

Собственно, ответ на вопрос:

[image: gg-zooming]

Comment: Спасибо, взял на вооружение данную шпаргалку.

Comment: @kikudryavtsev [там](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/) еще много полезных шпаргалок.